# Moment expansion of likelihood function

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, moment-problem

Let's say I have a binary hypothesis test described by a probability distribution $p(x;\theta)$ where $\theta$ takes two different values under each of the two hypothesis ($\theta_0$ under $\mathcal{H}_0$, the null hypothesis, and $\theta_1$ under $\mathcal{H}_1$). Using the Neyman-Pearson theorem, the test decide $\mathcal{H}_1$ if the likelihood is greater than a given threshold $\gamma$ $$\mathcal{L}(x)=\frac{p(x;\theta_1)}{p(x;\theta_0)}>\gamma$$
But in my situation, I know only the moments $m_n=\left<x^n\right>$ or, equivalently, the cumulants $k_n=\left<\left<x^n\right>\right>$ of the distribution. Is there a way to expand the likelihood functions in series of its moments?

Comment: Do you know the moments as a function of the parameter, or did you mean you know the sample moments? $\qquad$

Comment: I know the moments as a function of the parameters. I already found the solution some months ago (see below). Today I just edited the question for better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the solution. It is called Gram-Charlier expansion.
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series)